# Fetch a git remote branch to my local

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch `new-backlog-feature` I pushed it up to github, and a team member pulled the branch and made a change.  After his change he pushed back to GH, now I would like to pull his changes from the remote branch (same name) `new-backlog-feature`

How is this done?

I have tried

```
git fetch origin/new-backlog-feature
```

but the changes do not show up when I open up a text editor.  I can see the changes on GH.  Is there a step that I am missing after git fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must sync up your local repository with github:

```
git fetch origin
```

You can then show what's changed in the branch:

```
git log new-backlog-feature..origin/new-backlog-feature
gitk new-backlog-feature..origin/new-backlog-feature
```

If the changes are okay, you can run `git merge` to update your local branch:

```
# on branch new-backlog-feature
git merge origin/new-backlog-feature
```

If you have not created any local commits, this will result in a fast-forward merge. If you have local commits, this will create a new merge commit which rejoins both lines of history.

Answer (score 1):

**pull = fetch + merge** or **fetch = pull - merge**

You did only fetch the changes but in order to see them you need to merge them into your local branch.

The best way to proceed is to fetch the changes `git fetch origin` and then merging each branch with your local one `git merge origin/branch`. This is recommended rather than just `git pull origin` because you have more control on what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Fetch puts commits from the remote repo into your repo.  Checkout puts a particular commit in your worktree.  Merge combines commits with your current checkout.